# Comparison of atomic variables in C

Tags: c, linux, gcc, atomic, glibc

I have 2 atomic variables:

```
atomic_ulong overwrap_cnt = 0;
atomic_ulong overwrap_read_cnt = 0;
```

One thread does the increasing of overwrap_cnt (once):

```
overwrap_cnt++;
```

Another thread does the comparison in an endless loop:

```
while(1)
{
 if (overwrap_read_cnt == overwrap_cnt)
 {
  printf("or:%lu, ow:%lu \n",overwrap_read_cnt, overwrap_cnt);
 }
 usleep(100000);
}
```

However, the result is always the following:

```
or:0, ow:1
or:0, ow:1
or:0, ow:1
```

Somehow during the comparison the variables were equal, but when we printf them - we see that they are different. The result is the same for every iteration.

Can't I compare atomic variables like this? Or what is wrong?

It's on centos 7.5 with gcc (GCC) 4.9.2 20150212 (Red Hat 4.9.2-6)

Thanks.

Comment: what type is `atomic_ulong` ?

Comment: I think you'll need to wrap the entire `if` statement (and the increment) in protection. Your variables are individually atomic, but they are accessed twice in the `if` statement,, once for the comparison, again for the `printf`. They are locked down individually during each of those reads, but in between the comparison and the `printf`, the other thread could sneak in and increment `overwrap_cnt`

Comment: @KamilCuk something like `typedef _Atomic unsigned long atomic_ulong`, it is defined in `stdatomic.h`

Comment: Och indeed, sorry.

Comment: Well, have you tried using `atomic_store(&overwrap_cnt, atomic_load(&overwrap_cnt) + 1)` and `if (atomic_load(&...) == atomic_load(&...))` and so on?

Comment: You did not, by accident, type a `;` semicolon at the end of the if-statement ?

Comment: if your sleeping for 100ms you may as well use a mutex.  what is the reason you chose atomic vs mutex?

Comment: @yano The scenario you describe can happen once, but it does not explain why it keeps printing those lines

Comment: Although it is not supposed to make a difference, you may want to try marking the variables as `volatile` to see if the behavior changes.

Comment: @curiousguy12 nothing in the code presented makes it remotely possible to get three `printf`s of 0 and 1, atomicity and threading issues aside. Presumably there is code elsewhere which decrements/resets the two values that the OP deemed unnecessary for the question. But as always, an MCVE would be ideal...... on second thought, `overwrap_cnt` could wrap around, but unless it reaching 0 is synced with the comparison (it's not in the code), that scenario would be highly unlikely, but could explain 3 `printf`s from the presented code.

Answer (score 0):

Although the variables are individually atomic, your comparison loop is not.  Perhaps counter-intuitively, reading an atomic variable may generate more instructions than reading a non-atomic.

Consider for example if you had written code with the same behavior using GCC's atomic builtins:

```
while(1)
{
  unsigned long _tmp1 = __atomic_load_n(&overwrap_read_cnt, __ATOMIC_RELAXED);
  unsigned long _tmp2 = __atomic_load_n(&overwrap_cnt, __ATOMIC_RELAXED);
  if (_tmp1 == _tmp2)
  {
    _tmp2 = __atomic_load_n(&overwrap_cnt, __ATOMIC_RELAXED);
    _tmp1 = __atomic_load_n(&overwrap_read_cnt, __ATOMIC_RELAXED);
    printf("or:%lu, ow:%lu \n", _tmp1, _tmp2);
  }
  usleep(100000);
}
```

Although the values fetched for the comparison were determined to be equal, they may no longer be at the time they're fetched again for the printf call.

If you want to ensure the values used later are the same as those in the if statement, you should fetch them only once, and then use the cached values throughout the rest of the loop iteration.